# How to re-use pieces of lines several times?

Tags: java, variables

In this piece of code, `user.getBlockPos().down()` is used many times, how can I make it some kind of variable?

```
if (world.getBlockState(user.getBlockPos().down()) != SU.FLYING_BLOCK.getDefaultState() && world.getBlockState(user.getBlockPos().down()) != Blocks.BEDROCK.getDefaultState()) {
        world.breakBlock(user.getBlockPos().down(), true);
        world.setBlockState(user.getBlockPos().down(), SU.FLYING_BLOCK.getDefaultState());
        return TypedActionResult.success(ItemStack.EMPTY);
    } else return TypedActionResult.success(new ItemStack(SU.FLYING_BLOCK_ITEM));
```

Comment: Simply assign it to some variable of the proper type.  If it is something within the API you are using then  you will need to check the documentation to get that type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using development tools, you can view the parameter types returned by down (), define an object to receive it, and then you can use the object directly. For example, down () returns an object. You can directly use the

> object object= user.getBlockPos (). Down ();

, and then you can directly use object. If you are developing with idea, you can click down (), and then Ctrl + enter can view the source code